# Update values to negative based on another column

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, negative-number

I have a table that contains sales invoices and credit notes, both are held in the table as positive values.

I want to select the data and in the select statement change the credit note vales to be negative based on another column.

Any ideas?

Updated with added information

```
Key          Description            Type          Amount
--------------------------------------------------------
1            Invoice for 345         1             200
2            Invoice for 346         1             250
3            Invoice for 347         1             280
4            Credit  for 347         2             200
5            Invoice for 345         1             400
6            Credit note zz665       2             380
```

Desired result from select

```
Key          Description            Type          Amount
--------------------------------------------------------
1            Invoice for 345         1             200
2            Invoice for 346         1             250
3            Invoice for 347         1             280
4            Credit  for 347         2            -200
5            Invoice for 345         1             400
6            Credit note zz665       2            -380
```

thanks a lot, i have playing around with ABS but i cant figure out the exact usage to get my desired output.

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag would all help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that when type = 1, then positive and when type = 2 then negative.  If the type could include more values you will have to amend the case statement because everything other than 1 will be negative.

```
select
  key
, description
, type
, case
   when type = 1 then amount
  else
   amount * -1
  end as amount
```

Answer (score 1):

Just another option is `choose()`

**Example**

```
Select [Key] 
      ,[Description]
      ,[Type]
      ,[Amount] = [Amount]*choose([type],1,-1)
 From  YourTable
```

Comment: Thanks for the alternative.

Comment: Great option which is often overlooked.  This works so long as the [TYPE] field is properly populated with ones or twos.  If this CHOOSE() receives an invalid number the result will be NULL.  I guess it depends on how clean the data is.

Comment: @JimL Your observations are 100% correct.   Assuming a General Ledger type application, I would assume the [Type] would be well defined.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone has this question and is using DB2:

```
Select Key
      ,Description
      ,Type
      ,Amount
      ,Amount * (case when type = '1' then 1 else -1 end) as Amount_Accurate
 From  YourTable
```

- as a side note, if you're in my situation where a column named `charge_type` says either Credit or Debit, then you could do the following:

```
Select Key
      ,Description
      ,Type
      ,Amount
      ,Amount * (case when charge_type = 'Charge' then 1 else -1 end) as Amount_Accurate
 From  YourTable
```